# Reshaping dataset from file to tuple

Tags: python, database, numpy, dictionary

I have an issue which is relatively simple in principle but which is making me quite confused.

So I have a folder containing many different datafiles of the form shown below:

```
4
val__for_label_0    val_for_label_1 val_for_label_2 val_for_label_3  ...... 
A    value_1         value_2         value_3        value_4
B    value_1         value_2         value_3        value_4
C    value_1         value_2         value_3        value_4
D    value_1         value_2         value_3        value_4
```

For all these file I want to extract information and store it in the following way. 
For each file a tuple (int, dict, dict)

- where ‘int’ is the first number on the upper left corner.
- in the first dict I already know the labels and I want to fill it with the labels values this way: “some_label_i”:” val_for_label_i” for all the values on the second row.
- the second dictionary contains “letter”:”[value_1,value_2,value_3]”  in the same row, for each one of the other rows starting with a letter. I don’t need to include the 4th value on the rows.

Do you have suggestions how to do it in the most efficient, quick and powerful way? There is also someway to implement all the tuples (one from each of these files) in a single organized database easy to handle and access in python with numpy?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: More efficient compared to what? And shouldn't you mention the format of your files and how you want to store the retrieved information? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I meant “most” efficient, sorry! The file format is an .xyz file, but can be seen as a normal .txt! How to store the retrieved information in the more convenient and handly way was part of my issue...